# Pointers to 2D arrays C, C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm learning about pointers:

```
int x[10]; 
int *p = &x
```

this would make a pointer type `int` to the first element. So, if I had 2D array, I need to use double pointer: first pointer would point to the second dimension of the array. This means :

```
int x[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,9,9,9}};
```

and when I want to point to it I must declare the size of the second dimension like this, right ?

```
int *p[4] = x;
```

or there is another way by typing : `int **p`; ?

and `int *p[4]` is array of integer pointers which takes `4 * (sizeof(int*))`, right?

Comment: Just aside: try avoiding pointers alltogether in C++.  Use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: "_`int *p[4]` is array of integer pointers which takes `4 * (sizeof(int*))`, right?_" - Yes. And **always** compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra`). You'll then notice warnings about incompatible pointer types when you compile you code. Thus, it'll give you an indication that something is wrong.

Comment: well .. 
mingw32-g++.exe  -o............................
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)

and :

int x[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,987,9,9}};
int (*p)[4] = x;
printf("%d",p[2][1]);
printf("\nsize of *p is : %d \n",sizeof(p));
-------------------------------------------------------------- output :
987
size of *p is : 4

Comment: well... your first example is wrong (as anyone has already told you) and a compiler will give you a warning. Your second example is different from what you put in the comment `int *p[4]` vs `int (*p)[4]`. You label your output `size of *p` but then use `sizeof(p)` (p is a pointer and all pointers in C have the same size)... Maybe you should try to learn more

Comment: @xtofl You mean arrays, not pointers, right ? You can't go anywhere in C++ without pointers.

Comment: @Quentin: I should have said 'postponing the usage of' pointers.  Pointers are one of the hardest things to grasp, an can best be hidden below the beautiful concepts offered by  the standard library.  If you can spare an hour, take a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk !

Comment: @edc65 ok yeah i see ur point .. all im asking about is this : 
int x[2][5]; // <--------- this is double array of int
int (*p)[5]; // <-------------- is this array of pointers ? 

if yes .. i ve done sizeof(p) and it gives me 4 only ... why ?

Comment: I think you already have all the answers here. Anyway I'm going to add one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> this would make a pointer type (int) to first element ..

No.
`&x` is the address of array `x` and is of type `int (*)[10]` and you can't assign it to a `int *` type. Both are incompatible types.

> So, if I had 2D array, I need to use double pointer: first pointer would point to the second dimension of the array.

No.
In expressions, arrays converted to pointer to its first elements except when an operand of `sizeof` and unary `&` operator. Therefore, in this case the type of `x` will be `int (*)[4]` after conversion. You need a pointer to an array of 4 `int` instead of an array of 4 pointers

```
 int (*p)[4] = x;
```

Comment: well ,, yeah .. i ment the pointer points to an integer .. which is the first element of the array x ..

and my question is really this :
int (*p)[4] = x;

is this ^^^ 4 pointers (array of pointers) or 1 pointer  ?

Comment: `in *p[4]` declares an array of *4 pointers*. `p` is an array here.

Comment: Not possible for sure. It should be 16 bytes if p is an array.

Answer (score 3):

To add, the first example is not correct.

`x` is an array of 10 ints. `p` is a pointer to int and not a pointer to an array of 10 ints. When assigned to `p`, `x` decays to the type pointer to int.

The assignment should be simply:

```
int* p = x;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example program:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x[3][4] = { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 987, 9, 9 } }; 
    int(*p)[4] = x; printf("p[2][1] %d", p[2][1]); 
    printf("\nsizeof(p) is : %d \nsizeof(*p) is : %d\n", sizeof(p), sizeof(*p)); 
}
```

**Output**

```
p[2][1] 987
sizeof(p) is : 4
sizeof(*p) is : 16
```

In my system (as in yours) int and pointers are 32 bits. So the size of a pointer is 4 and the size of an int is 4 too.

`p` is a pointer first of all. Not an array. A pointer. It's size is 4 no less no more. **That's the answer to your question**

Now, just to add some useful information:

`p` is a pointer to an array of 4 integers. The size of what `p` points to is 4*4==16. (Try to change `int` to `short` in the example program, you'll have `sizeof(*p) is : 8`)

I can assign `p=x` because the type is correct, now `p` contains the address of x and p[0] is the same as x[0] (the same array of 4 int). `p[2][3]` is the same as `x[2][3]` and `*(p[2]+3)`. `p[2]` points to the element 2 of x and `p[2]+3` points to the element 3 of `x[2]`. (all indexing is 0 based)

Answer (score -2):

```
// Here is not complicated matrix of size
int p[2][4]={
              {1,2,3,4},
              {5,6,7,8}
            };
// points to the first Elements :: ptr
int (*ptr)[0] = &p;
// Now have the same adresse ( ptr and p )
printf("Hello world! %d \n",ptr[1][3]); // show  4
```

Comment: Untitled1.cpp|35|error: cannot convert 'int (*)[2][4]' to 'int (*)[0]' in initialization|